# How to use document ready in Typescript angular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have tried to apply the below code in Typescript parent controller but it is not working.

Did I miss anything?

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first').focus();
     });
```

Comment: Why can't you use tabindex to get the focus?

Comment: I want to apply focus only for the first form element to all pages. If I use autofocus i have to apply every page. Looking for generic option.

Comment: I believe tabindex will work for the visible form. So at a given time one 1 form is visible that form will get focus. Now if you do have more than 1 forms visible per page it should give focus to the first focusable element of first form. Trying to understand why generic out of the box functionality supported by mist browser is not sufficient. Do you have an element that is not focusable?

Comment: ok thanks..  Here the example and looking for first control has to be focused while switching the page. Can you pls your logic here http://fiddle.jshell.net/95wEL/42/

Comment: You could do it with the querySelector: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4k0e1e7q/

Comment: How and when are you loading your Angular and jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your jQuery did not finish loading before your AngularJS calls its `angular.element(document).ready` method.

Try calling the jQuery `$(document).ready` method as well and check which one gets triggered first like I have done in this little Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ubw0w2mo7wkPZwBld82N?p=preview

Executing the jQuery method after making sure both are ready works for me (tested in Safari Version 10.1 and Chromium Version 57.0.2978.0)
http://plnkr.co/edit/Oe5dcFmhLPaatoI2qXBr?p=preview

However, In general there is no need for jQuery and you might want to think about an AngularJS only solution.

Comment: to minus an answer without saying why should be a violation